# Ipn paypal curl_setopt

Tags: php, mysql, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hello friends I been having a really hard time the past 5 day just trying to figure out whys is it that my script for paypal doesn't want to work in my website and i have come to a conclusion that is the `curl_setopt` is wrong for some reason because i have tried `IPN` simulator from Paypal and my query's execute that's without the `curl_setopt`, and i really dont know how to solve this problem.

```
<?php
$dbusername     = 'whatever'; //db username
$dbpassword     = 'whatever'; //db password
$dbhost     = 'whatever'; //db host
$dbname     = 'whatever'; //db name
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
 $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
 $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
 // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
 } 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
 if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
 } else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
 }
 $req .= "&$key=$value";
 }


 // STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

  $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

  // In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
  // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
  // of the certificate as shown below.
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
 if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {

if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

       // mysqli_select_db($dbname, $conn);

        // insert in our IPN record table
        $query = "INSERT INTO dale
        (itransaction_id)
        VALUES
        ('Error')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);

// error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
curl_close($ch);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check whether the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL)
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
else
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];

// Insert your actions here
if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
       // mysqli_select_db($dbname, $conn);

        // insert in our IPN record table
        $query = "INSERT INTO dale
        (itransaction_id)
        VALUES
        ('success')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);

  } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
   // log for manual investigation

  if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

       // mysqli_select_db($dbname, $conn);

        // insert in our IPN record table
        $query = "INSERT INTO dale
        (itransaction_id)
        VALUES
        ('fail')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
  }
  ?>
```

This is a class that i got from Paypal and i have tried many other classes but none seem to work.

Comment: curl_setopt = curl set option, so which option do you think is at fault? you could just remove one at a time to test

Comment: You need to log your curl error, which is probably going to show an ssl handshake failure.  [Read this](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vunerability/) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was a change from paypal posted data recently (Jan 30 2016) the mc_currency and datecreation fields are now null.